# How do I use ng-repeat and filter properties over an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

so my data is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "userid": "a",
        "age": 19,
        "name": "john"
    },
    {
        "userid": "b",
        "age": 119,
        "name": "joy"
    },
    {
        "userid": "b",
        "age": 119,
        "name": "jesse"
    }
]
```

And my array is `myarray:["a","b"]`

ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="objects in data
{{objects.age}}
```

How do I use ng-filter so that only those objects whose userid is in myarray
i.e only a and b are shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a general filter:

```
  angular.module('App')
    .filter("byPropertyInArray", function() {
      return function(objects, propertyName, values) {
        return objects.filter(function(object) {
          return values.indexOf(object[propertyName]) !== -1;
        });
      }
    });
```

Then use it in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in data | byPropertyInArray:'userid':myarray">
  {{object.age}}
</div>
```

Assuming that scope contains `data` as the list of objects and `myarray` as the list of ids.

Answer (score 2):

Since you using angular, you can do the same using filters.

```
app.filter('myCustomFilter', function() {

  return function(items) {
    var arrayToReturn = [];
        ["a", "b"].forEach(function(id){
          //find element with userid a or b
          var f = items.find(function(d){return d.userid == id});
            if(f){
                //on find push that in the arrayToReturn
                arrayToReturn.push(f);
            }
        });
    return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```

Now use your filter in the ng repeat like this

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | myCustomFilter">
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3h0stL0q/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for it.

It keeps the array with the result and looks up if an `userid` is in the result set. If it is not, then the actual `userid` is pushed to the result.

```js
var data = [{ userid: "a", age: 19, name: "john" }, { userid: "b", age: 119, name: "joy" }, { userid: "b", age: 119, name: "jesse" }],
    filtered = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        ~r.indexOf(a.userid) || r.push(a.userid);
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```